# Add PySpark RDD as new column to pyspark.sql.dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark.sql.dataframe where each row is a news article. I then have a RDD that represents the words contained in each article. I want to add the RDD of words as a column named 'words' to my dataframe of new articles. I tried

```
df.withColumn('words', words_rdd )
```

but I get the error

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

The DataFrame looks something like this

```
Articles
the cat and dog ran
we went to the park
today it will rain
```

but I have 3k news articles.

I applied a function to clean the text such as remove stop words and I have a RDD that looks like this:

```
[[cat, dog, ran],[we, went, park],[today, will, rain]]
```

I'm trying to get my Dataframe to look like this:

```
Articles                 Words
the cat and dog ran      [cat, dog, ran]
we went to the park      [we, went, park]
today it will rain       [today, will, rain]
```

Comment: please share example data, you probably need to join though.

Comment: How are they matched? why are the words for [the, cat, and, dog, ran] matched to the article the cat and dog ran and not another article?

Answer (score 13):

**Disclaimer**:

Spark `DataFrame` in general has no strictly defined order. Use at your own risk.

Add index to existing `DataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df_index = spark.createDataFrame(
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex(),
    StructType([StructField("data", df.schema), StructField("id", LongType())])
)
```

Add index to `RDD` and convert to `DataFrame`:

```
words_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    words_rdd.zipWithIndex(),
    StructType([
        StructField("words", ArrayType(StringType())),
        StructField("id", LongType())
    ])
)
```

Join both and select required fields:

```
df_index.join(words_df, "id").select("data.*", "words")
```

**Caution**

There are different solutions, which might work in specific cases, but don't guarantee performance and or correctness. These include:

- Using `monotonically_increasing_id` as a `join` key - in general case not correct.
- Using `row_number()` window function as a join key - unacceptable performance implication and in general not correct if there is no specific order defined.
- Using `zip` on `RDDs` - can work if and only if both structures have the same data distribution (should work in this case).

**Note**:

In this specific case you shouldn't need `RDD`. `pyspark.ml.feature` provides a variety of `Transformers`, which should work well for you.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

df = spark.createDataFrame(
     ["the cat and dog ran", "we went to the park", "today it will rain"],
         "string"
).toDF("Articles")

Pipeline(stages=[
    RegexTokenizer(inputCol="Articles", outputCol="Tokens"), 
    StopWordsRemover(inputCol="Tokens", outputCol="Words")
]).fit(df).transform(df).show()
# +-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
# |           Articles|              Tokens|          Words|
# +-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
# |the cat and dog ran|[the, cat, and, d...|[cat, dog, ran]|
# |we went to the park|[we, went, to, th...|   [went, park]|
# | today it will rain|[today, it, will,...|  [today, rain]|
# +-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
```

The list of stop words can be provided using `stopWords` parameter of the `StopWordsRemover`, for example:

```
StopWordsRemover(
    inputCol="Tokens",
    outputCol="Words",
    stopWords=["the", "and", "we", "to", "it"]
)
```

Comment: In my case all rows are randomly generated, so order is unimportant. This should work well, thank you.

Comment: @bendl In general you still prefer methods, which don't require combining structures. If you generate random data, then `udf` or `map` should work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to join the rdd back to the dataframe, I would rather create a new column from "Articles" directly. There are multiple ways to do it, here are my 5 cents:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)    # sc is the sparkcontext

x = [Row(Articles='the cat and dog ran'),Row(Articles='we went to the park'),Row(Articles='today it will rain')]
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(x)

df2 = df.map(lambda x:tuple([x.Articles,x.Articles.split(' ')])).toDF(['Articles','words'])
df2.show()
```

You get the following output:

```
Articles                 words
the cat and dog ran      [the, cat, and, dog, ran]
we went to the park      [we, went, to, the, park]
today it will rain       [today, it, will, rain]
```

Let me know if you were looking to achieve something else.

Comment: That's pretty much what I want but I have 3k articles and I want to apply a function to each of those articles to perform some cleaning (not just split) and put it in a dataframe like you have above. This is my first time using pyspark so I'm not sure of the best approaches.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file of your actual data. Any arbitrary function can be applied with the help of udf in spark

Comment: got it to work using udf: newdf = df.withColumn("words",udf_clean_text("articles")) thanks!!

Comment: If this solved your problem, make sure to mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach but effective would be to use [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration). You can:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(["the cat and dog ran", "we went to the park", "today it will rain", None], 
"string" ).toDF("Articles")

split_words = udf(lambda x : x.split(' ') if x is not None else x, StringType())
df = df.withColumn('Words', split_words(df['Articles']))

df.show(10,False)
>>
+-------------------+-------------------------+
|Articles           |Words                    |
+-------------------+-------------------------+
|the cat and dog ran|[the, cat, and, dog, ran]|
|we went to the park|[we, went, to, the, park]|
|today it will rain |[today, it, will, rain]  |
|null               |null                     |
+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

I added check for None because it very usual to have in your data bad lines. You can drop them easily after splitting or  before ,with dropna.

But in my opinion if you want to do this as a preparation task for Text analytics it would be probably to your best interest to build a Pipeline as @user9613318 suggests in his answer

Answer (score -2):

```
rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 5])
# make some transformation on rdd1:
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda n: True if n % 2 else False)
# Append each row in rdd2 to those in rdd1.
rdd1.zip(rdd2).collect()
```

Comment: Please explain how and why your code solves the problem or improves the code from the question.