# PySpark: Convert RDD to column in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a spark dataframe using which I am calculating the Euclidean distance between a row and a given set of corrdinates. I am recreating a structurally similar dataframe 'df_vector' here to explain better.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
df_example = spark.createDataFrame(arr, ['A','B','C'])
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[x for x in df_example.columns],outputCol='features')
df_vector = assembler.transform(df_example).select('features') 

>>> df_vector.show()
+-------------+
|     features|
+-------------+
|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|
|[4.0,5.0,6.0]|
+-------------+

>>> df_vector.dtypes
[('features', 'vector')]
```

As you can see the `features` column is a vector. In practice, I get this vector column as the output of a `StandardScaler`. Anyway, since I need to calculate Euclidean distance, I do the following

```
rdd = df_vector.select('features').rdd.map(lambda r: np.linalg.norm(r-b))
```

where

```
b = np.asarray([0.5,1.0,1.5])
```

I have all the calculations I need but I need this `rdd` as a column in `df_vector`. How do I go about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add PySpark RDD as new column to pyspark.sql.dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124010/add-pyspark-rdd-as-new-column-to-pyspark-sql-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a new rdd, you could use an `UDF`:

```
norm_udf = udf(lambda r: np.linalg.norm(r - b).tolist(), FloatType())
df_vector.withColumn("norm", norm_udf(df.features))
```

Make sure `numpy` is defined on the worker nodes.

Comment: This works. Thanks. But is there a way we can do this without using udf? We have to handle larger datasets (~10 million records or so) and udfs tend decrease the performance.

Comment: @ClockSlave There is no other good way I can think of right now. I don't believe it should have worse performance than converting to rdd, doing the transformation and then go back, so it's something at least.

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle performance issues might be to use `mapPartitions`. The idea would be, at a partition level, to convert `features` to an array and then calculate the norm on the whole array (thus implicitly using numpy vectorisation). Then do some housekeeping to get the form you want. For large datasets this might improve performance:

Here is the function which calculates the norm at partition level:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
def getnorm(vectors):
    # convert vectors into numpy array
    vec_array=np.vstack([v['features'] for v in vectors])
    # calculate the norm
    norm=np.linalg.norm(vec_array-b, axis=1)
    # tidy up to get norm as a column
    output=[Row(features=x, norm=y) for x,y in zip(vec_array.tolist(), norm.tolist())]
    return(output)
```

Applying this using `mapPartitions` gives an RDD of Rows which can then be converted to a DataFrame:

```
df_vector.rdd.mapPartitions(getnorm).toDF()
```